# Connect Python/Django App to a Free Tier Oracle cloud Database

Tags: python, django-allauth, django-database, oracle-autonomous-db

Im having some issues getting my app to connect to Oracles Free Tier Autonomous Database.

I keep getting the following error when attempting to start up the server.

```
(venv) me@computer app % python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File c/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app//Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 250, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 576, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 284, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 243, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/me/Projects/blah/app/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 250, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 'libclntsh.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libclntsh.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

I added the following to my settings.py file as per the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-DATABASES) update the fields with the information I got from my tnsnames.ora file and I am still unable to connect via the app. But I am able to connect through VS Code and run queries/create tables etc.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'Database_Name', #AS SEEN FROM THE ORACLE CLOUD INTERFACE
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'HOST', #AS SEEN IN THE TNSNAMES.ORA FILE
        'PORT': '1522',
    }
}
```

I have tried installing cx_oracle 8 & oracledb as well an neither of those resolved the issue.

Thanks for any assistance in resolving this issue.

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message?

Comment: @KlausD. I did. I am following the guide at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-databases, my three files are in their correct location but I am still getting the same error.